# Simple estate planning

Tags: estate-planning

Married couple + child. Own a house (with a mortgage) and a few savings accounts.
Want to leave everything to each other in the event of death. If both die then to our child. Also want to select a guardian.

What do we need? Joint / separate wills? A trust? Should we go with a lawyer or can this be done independently with online software?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: LegalZoom and others offer online systems that purport to produce these kinds of documents based on a user answering questions in order to customize the documents. This is not a recommendation at all. I upvoted the "Use a Lawyer" answer.

Answer (score 2):

### Use a lawyer

There is no such thing as a "simple" estate.

Estate planning involves considering things such as tax implications, further issue of the relationship, further (or existing) issue outside the relationship, death of your child(ren), simultaneous deaths, the age of the child(ren) given that death can occur from anywhere from today to 100 years from now, you winning the lottery tomorrow, jointly owned assets, individually owned assets, assets where the beneficiary is based on someone else's discretion (life insurance), divorce, separation, guardians, death of guardians, trusts, trustees, death of trustees etc.

Still think you can handle it yourself?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I feel like you may have made things a bit more complicated. I'm generally ok with selecting the most common "default" actions to these situations.
i.e. if one of us dies the other gets everything. If both die the child gets it. If all die the grandparents, and so on. If we win the lottery or gain any additional funds the same rules apply. I wouldn't suddenly give the lottery money to someone else.

If we divorce we'll end up paying lawyers a ton of money anyway in which case we can discuss those issues again.

Comment: @Dandan - and can you write a will that will work now and when you and your wife split in 5 years time? Your lawyer can.

Comment: If we split we can revisit the will, since we'll most likely be spending money on lawyers anyway.